# Does Google Analytics capture Javascript redirects?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Let’s say i use this code to redirect visitor :
window.location = ‘http://differentsite.com’

Differentsite.com is foreign site without my Google Analytics code.

Does Google Analytics log the redirect? Google Analytics will show me the visitor has left the page, but can i see the destination?

Comment: This sounds like a question better asked on the google analytics support forums. They can tell you for sure.

Comment: @Nope This is a fine question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Brad I didn't say it's **not** fine, I'm saying the horses mouth might be a more reliable source. Specially with Google.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't.  It's no different than any other link somewhere else.

You can make a logging request in your script right before setting `window.location`, but you would have to wait for it to finish, delaying your users a bit.